# How do you store a string in a register? is it possible?Assembly x8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
      .MODEL SMALL
      .STACK 100h
      .DATA

      men1          db 0dh,0ah,"     $"
      men2          db 0dh,0ah,"                                 MAIN MENU$"
      men3          db 0dh,0ah,"                            [1]Calculator$"
      men4          db 0dh,0ah,"                            [2]Conversion$" 
      men5          db 0dh,0ah,"                            [3]Exit$"
```

is there a way to display this strings using only registers?

Answer (score 5):

> How do you store a string in a register? is it possible?

No, unless it's 2 bytes or shorter.  (Or you split it across multiple registers.)  This is why you normally only store a *pointer* to it, and why C functions like `strchr` take a `char*` arg: there's no way to pass an arbitrary-length string by value in a register.

---

> is there a way to display this strings using only registers?

Sure, one character at a time, using immediates.  (Of course, video RAM is eventually memory, or at least in physical address space.  You have to get the data out of CPU registers somewhere, but it doesn't have to start in data memory.

Of course it's much more efficient if it is in memory so you can loop over it, instead of having to fully unroll like

```
mov  ah, 0Eh       ; BIOS service number for teletype output, set up once ahead of time

mov al, 'M'
int 10h            ; BIOS teletype output
mov al, 'A'
int 10h
...
```

(That [BIOS call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) doesn't destroy `AH`.)

`mov byte ptr [video_ram], 'M'` would be another way, where `video_ram` is some combination of segment and offset that references it.  That could get you down to **4 bytes per character stored**,  opcode + modrm + disp8 + imm8 if you have a zeroed register as a base, and use `DS` as the segment.  e.g.

```
    mov  bx, vga_base
    mov  ds, bx
    xor  bx, bx

    mov byte ptr  [bx+0], 'M'    ; assuming VGA text mode
    mov byte ptr  [bx+2], 'E'    ; where even bytes are chars
    mov byte ptr  [bx+4], 'N'    ; and odd bytes are attributes (e.g. FG/BG colour)
    ...
    mov  byte ptr [bx+126], 'x'
    add  bx, 128
    ; signed 8-bit displacement only goes up to +127
    mov  byte ptr [bx+0],  'y'
    ; you *could* increment by 256, and start with [bx-128] instead of 0.
```

You could set the attributes as well by using word stores instead of byte.

Note that this doesn't even use registers for the data.  With `mov  byte ptr [0], 'M'`, we wouldn't even be using a register, but that would cost an extra byte per instruction for an absolute disp16 in the addressing mode.